confused with the notion of probability
I understand probability as two processes;

We "do" something (or something is "happening"). lets call it the random experiment, and
We "expect" something from this happening.

Then we define probability as the chances/likeliness/number_of_ways of our expectation, among the all possible outcomes of this happening i.e. random experiment.
So when we consider the problems like;
"there are n1 red and n2 black balls in a bag, out of which m balls are chosen. So what is the probability of having k1 red and k2 black balls in this m chosen balls?"
As we can see, both the processes are well defined here. As,
happening/doing: choosing m balls
expectation: having k1 red, and k2 black balls from the m chosen balls.
So the probability of the given expectation* can be defined as;
*(not meant as the expected value or expectation in probability. It just represents what we are seeking for in that particular experiment).
$$P = \frac{(number\ of\ ways\ of\ choosing\ k1\ red,\ and\ k2\ black\ balls\ from\ m\ balls)}{(number\ of\ ways\ of\ choosing\ m\ balls\ from\ n1\ red,\ and\ n2\ green\ balls)}$$
$$P = \frac{mC(k1).(m-k1)C(k2)}{(n1+n2)Cm}$$
But when we encounter problems like

"What is the probability of choosing a number from a set of n numbers?",
"what is the probability of choosing k1 red, and k2 black balls from the n1 red, and n2 black balls?"

I get confused what process/experiment we are expecting it from? As there is no well defined process of experiment happening.
My dilemma started when I encountered this question from codeforces;

As here, we see that every time either alice or bob picks a ball and add its value to his score. And in order to find the expected value of the scores of them, we need to compute the probability of picking any random ball by alice/bob?
So how this probability can be calculated here?
And also if there would be n-k+1 ways to pick the special ball at every place between two normal balls. Like;
-, *, -, *, -, *, -, *, -
where, * represents the placement of normal balls, "_" represents the placement of special balls.
So how can we find the probability and then the expected value of such arrangment where we can have "n-k+1" ways to pick the special ball at every spot between every two adjacent normal balls.
I am just confused. Please help me.
Thanks.

Not sure what you are asking.  Yes, people sometimes write ambiguously, and sometimes leave off details.  In such a case, the reader must ask for clarification and/or detail or supply that on their own.  Is that what you are asking?

You are right that statements of probability are meaningless without a random process to back them.  When no such process is mentioned explicitly, authors are generally assuming a “maximal entropy” process of some sort appropriate for the local context (e.g. a uniform distribution).

In the case of the problem you quote, I don't really see any ambiguity.  Clearly we are to assume uniformity...each ball is equally likely to be drawn from those available.   That's what people usually mean by "randomly" is such a context.

Should add:  your comments on expectation are hard to follow.  Keep in mind that the "expected" outcome need not be particularly likely, nor even possible.  Rather it represents an average over the possible outcomes, weighted by the probability distribution.  When you toss a fair die, for instance, you "expect" to get a $3.5$ though that is, in fact, an impossible outcome.

@lulu okk I get it. But that's not what I am concerned about. My main concern is how to find the probability of picking any random balls from the set of n balls where first k are special, and how can I find their expected value. (As mentioned in the codeforces problem).

Still not following...at any point, both players know how many special balls remain and how many un-special balls remain, so the probability (at each stage) is obvious.  Keep in mind:  this is a programming challenge, so the overall question need not have a pleasant closed form solution.

For small $(n,k)$ straight simulation should be no problem.  I suggest implementing code for that.  Then you can look at ways to optimize the code, as straight simulation probably won't work for $10^9$ balls.

@lulu since the random experiment is not mentioned explicitly here so I assume the sample space to be the uniform. So now initially I have n balls to pick from. So the probability of picking it, due to 'uniformity' is 1/n. Now let say this is special ball, so we again can pick from remaining n-1. So the probability is 1/n-1.

@lulu but in this way, at every step of picking, we have many options so we could go into any valid permutation of these balls.

@lulu I am just confused how we can determine the probability here ?? as there are so many combinations of these balls both players can pick ?? so how can we take the probabilities of each of them into account ??

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The usual approach would be to set up a recursion.  Good programming exercise.  Again, not sure it's going to get you as deep as you need to get.  True, the $10^9$ takes the possible values into account, but even so $n$ might be as large as $400,000$ if I am reading correctly.  That's asking a lot.

But, again, try.  Get a recursion going.  See if you can get $n$ up to $10^4$, say.

@lulu I can do dynamic programming but the problem is, wont we get different score for each combinations and so the different expected values of their scores ?? Then how can I uniquely determine the expected values of both player for the given n balls ??

Again:  try!  It's a programming exercise, so try programming.  Work out special cases ($k=0$ makes it easy.  Why?).  Even by hand you should be able to handle $n=5$ or $6$.

@lulu if k=0, then the solution is pretty straightforward. Just give half of the balls or its ceil value to alice then remaining half to bob. And the expected value would be;
for alice- ceil(s/2), and for bob- s/2.
where s-average value of all the normal balls.
The problem arises when we introduce the special balls. Now once we pick any special ball, we can again choose any random ball from remaining which may include the special one again. Thats where it is getting tricky to me.
